# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

This error I see everywhere but I still find no solution to my deployment. 
I am using Eclipse Luna, jdk6, Spring, hibernate (3.3.2 GA), and maven 3.2.3, I run the application on a glassfish 3.1.2 server and then I receive this error in my server's log:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stateMachineManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain2/applications/moon-web-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/moon-commons-1.0.jar!/spring/context/orm/applicationContext-orm.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheDAO': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain2/applications/moon-web-1.0/WEB-INF/lib/moon-commons-1.0.jar!/spring/context/orm/applicationContext-orm.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
```

I found somewhere that this may be caused by the cglib (1.2_3) that I have replaced with cglib-nodep(1.2_3) and removed the asm as mentionned in some questions already asked. I am still receiving the same error on deployment.

Any help is most appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** The original error thrown by glassfish is the following, I only traced the first "caused by" for the above error:

```
 [#|2014-12-19T16:09:41.997+0100|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.xml.ws.server.http|_ThreadID=21;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WSSERVLET11 : échec de l'analyse du descripteur d'exécution : java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have solved the issue. I noticed that in the log file of my glassfish server there was an error mentionning unability to find my reference to the handlerchain for my webservices. After googling this, i found this was a bug reported in the 3.1.2.2 version of glassfish. The solution hence is just to upgrade the server. I run currently glassfish 4.1 with the respective jre7 of course and my application is deployed successfully. 
Thanks everyone, I hope this solves someone else's problem one day!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know "init" methods are used to implement constructors in bytecode. So I think there is a wrong constructor call. There is no ClassWriter constructor which accepts boolean argument. Please try to use latest asm jar.

Comment: This is a rather weird problem, because a few days ago, the code was working just fine, I just added on some webservices and touched nothing else. I even reverted to the initial state and it just doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Hi again @mathasmlang, I noticed your edit, I'm still dealing with the same problem. This time i tried to deploy and old generated war that used to deploy just fine. And I was surpised when glassfish threw the very same error one more time. I then reinstalled glassfish and the problem persists. 
I will try however to include the latest asm version, but as i said above, i used cglib-nodep that makes asm not needed and still got to the same issue. I'm more puzzled than ever.

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the late comment, I had a few troubles with maven, so i tried the latest version of ASM as you kindly suggested. This has not solved the issue.